# O notation for my algorithm

Tags: big-o

I want to compare three algorithms in case of steps of calculation, but I'm not very familiar with the O notation. The steps of calculation for each algorithm depend on three parameters (x,y,z):
algorithm 1) number_of_steps = x^2 * y * z - xyz
algorithm 2) number_of_steps = x^2 * y^2 * z - xyz
algorithm 3) number_of_steps = x^2 * y^2 * z^2 - xyz
There is not a huge difference between x, y and z - maybe one of the value is twice or triple another one, but not more.
How would it look in o notation? There are some solutions I can think about:
O1(n) vs. O2(n*y) vs. O3(n*y*z)
or
O1(n^4) vs. O2(n^5) vs. O3(n^6) - if x, y and z are nearly equal
or just
O1(x^2 * y * z) vs. O2(x^2 * y^2 * z) vs. O3(x^2 * y^2 * z^2)
Which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If max(x,y,z)/min(x,y,z) <= 3 (or less than any fixed number), then your complexities are

Algorithm 1: O(x^4) = O(y^4) = O(z^4)
Algorithm 2: O(x^5) = O(y^5) = O(z^5)
Algorithm 3: O(x^6) = O(y^6) = O(z^6)

If all you know is that x,y,z are at least 2, you can write

Algorithm 1: O(x^2 * y * z)
Algorithm 2: O(x^2 * y^2 * z)
Algorithm 3: O(x^2 * y^2 * z^2)

Of course you could always write them out in full like O(x^2 * y * z - xyz), but the simpler versions are better when possible.